# How to exclude externally referenced assemblies when measuring code coverage in VS10?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-coverage, testdriven.net

When measuring code coverage in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate with TestDriven.Net and the built-in coverage tool, two external assemblies, i.e. not project references, get included in the analysis.

How do I remove them?

Another way to solve my problem would be:

How to only measure coverage for referenced "projects", not binaries?